# Why won't my robo arm spin right?

Tags: animation, armature, bones, constraints, inverse-kinematics

I'd like this shoulder to spin only along the x axis whith the IK of the arm. The IK Lock axis switches aren't doing much though. I need everything to deform mechanically and rigidly adhering to those pivots in the models.

[image]

[image]

This is the result when I shorten the IK chain to 2 excluding the shoulder bone.

[image]

This is with the IK chain at 3 and ALL the axis locked on the shoulder bone.This doesn't make any sense to meh!

[image]

The right arm pivots behave correctly in FK. I'd like the IK elbow to move like it does in this animation.

Comment: Don't use a pole target, and lock the first bone in the 3-chain in all but Y axis.  Further help, I'd need a file.

Comment: Perfect! That fixed the shoulder. Thank you! How would yolu control the direction of the elbow in this case?

Comment: When I bend the arm backwards, the elbow flips forward now. Grabbing any  of the IK effected bones to spin them just causes wierd snappy fliippy results.

Comment: Further help, I need a file.  Your pics don't give me the information I need.

Comment: I added him to the question.

Comment: Try setting min and max rotation values for Arm.R and for Arm.R.001. so they don't overrotate while keeping axes locked.

Comment: That's definitely better, but the arm is flipping 180 when you bring the ik above or below rest pose with the arm pulled forward or back. I'm newish to rigging a full character, so I'm sorry if any of this basic. I've just had a hard time finding answers for my specific issues.

Comment: Is there no way to achieve this locked shoulder rotation while still using an elbow Pole Target?

Comment: It twitches because it's poorly designed (from a robot design standpoint, not a Blender standpoint.)  It can't reach many reasonable positions of the IK target.  A pole target would make no sense for this design, because there are only 2 solutions (when there are any) and they're discontinuous, 180 degree rotations of each other.  A better designed robot would have both hinges in the same axis.

Comment: His pivots are based on human joints rather than good robot design. I have the pivots in the direction I need them for the visual effect intended. What I'm trying to figure out is if there is a rigging based solution that would allow me to dictate the direction of the elbow (like a pole target) that doesn't break the shoulder IK axis locks. I'd like to be able to select which of the two solutions it has to choose between. I realize that I'm probably looking at an FK future, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: No, you don't understand.  This is not based on a human arm.  A human arm has more range of motion in the shoulder than this does-- it is a ball joint, not a hinge.  If you make that joint a ball joint, it will be doable.  You need to spend time thinking about the structure you made and what it is capable of.  If you want to choose between the two positions possible for the elbow, rotate the forearm in its axis.  It will prefer the bend it has before the IK is evaluated.  Again, these two orientations are not continuous (because there are only two of them.)

Comment: I really appreciate your persistent help here Nathan. You've gotten me a lot closer to figuring this out. I'd understand if you tapped out. The issue has evolved of course so if you're done I'll post another question. If you're still in the fight I reposted the .blend in the question including an FK animation that shows the kind of thing I'm looking for out of my IK. Whether non-human like, poorly designed , or otherwise I get the rotations I want when in FK. I really hope to find an IK solution to pointing that elbow without the unpredictable twitchy manual rotation of the arm bone in IK.

Comment: The .blend has changed now. Sorry about the mess up.

Comment: @ZachBowen Took a look at your new file.  I'm afraid all that you can do to match your FK animation with IK involves some manual keyframing of at least one bone to get Blender to handle the angles right.  The easiest bone to keyframe is Shoulder.  Blender is just choking on a lot of these angles.  It might be interesting to take a look at the structure in an earlier version-- I believe there were some recent, unmentioned changes to IK.

Comment: Thanks again Nathan. I'll try the older version idea. Outside of that I've posted a new question regarding this new problem since i believe you've answered this one perfectly. I'm just hoping someone knows some obscure trick that'll get me there. Rigging is still a bit arcane to me so who knows.

Comment: @ZachBowen Wait.  To match that FK animation exactly with IK, all you have to do is rotate Arm.R -90 degrees in X axis.  You can do this with a local space limit rotation constraint if you want.  No guarantee this will work great with all other animations though.  I would be tempted to add an extra Y axis bone (parent of shoulder) with +1 chain length to create "negative" stiffness in shoulder, as shoulder must rotate 180 degrees, without any other bones wanting to ever rotate >90 degrees, but not necessary for the anim you have.

Comment: I gave that a shot. It really isn't too bad, but I may have to stick with FK after all. I'm also going to try some simulation assisted animation with cascadeur.